# Curl error when installing Bioconductor packages with Microsoft R Open 3.5.0

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm trying to install Bioconductor packages with Microsoft R Open 3.5.0 seems to fail not sure what is the issue.

This is what I'm trying to do

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("BiocInstaller")
```

But I keep getting an error about "curl" had non-zero exit. 
How can I install the packages of Bioconductor?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. Your first paragraph seems to be about installing R but the last one suggests you have already installed it. Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post, [edit] and ask one, specific and clear question. Thanks!

Comment: updated my question ..iim getting this "curl' non-zero exit which wanted to post the error but closed my terminal so lost the exact error message

Comment: Then please run the command again and then add the error message to the your question. We can't help you solve an error if you don't show it.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment yet but from what you said it seems that you need to install additional libraries like the one you mentioned: "curl".

from the R terminal you should type:

```
install.packages("curl")
```

then R will install the package. Not sure if there are some other dependencies. If yes R will return you some error message in which there are some package names you need to install.

EDIT:

of course, after installing all the required packages you should be able to install biocLite too.

Comment: cd /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.1/lib64/R/library/  inside the path i can see the curl so why still i get the error i'm not sure

Comment: try loading the curl package from the R terminal and see if it actually works (`library(curl)`). Maybe some libraries are missing. I use linux and curl requires additional libraries that are not installed by R but are system's libraries.

Comment: yeah i did check the system level libraries as i can see using this "locate libcurl "so still not sure why the non-zero exit

Comment: finally after some time it did work.

Comment: sorry for not replying! if you solved the issue just post how you did it. This will help other people having the same problems!

Comment: earlier it was not showing any error no idea what was going on but later it showed up the dependencies  error which i installed it sort of fixed the problem ..but the way i used to update using CRAN is now no longer working with Microsoft R open here i can;t define the repository how to fix that any suggestion ?

Comment: @krushnachChandra, sorry for this very late reply, I must have lost your comment...have you solved your issue? otherwise I believe you should open another question with more details.

Comment: well thank you for your late response , i had few other issues as well .So i reverted to the base R